# Generate template for a group of files

Tags: angularjs, templates, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have an angular project with different packages. Each package includes a scss, a controller, a html template and a config file.
E.g.

```
dashboard/
    dashboard.tmpl.html
    dashboard.scss
    dashboard.controller.js
    dashboard.config.js
```

Each file also includes some content where the package name is required.

My current solution is to create all the files by myself and fill them with a live template.

So my question is if it is possible to do this automatically or all 4 files with just one command?

Comment: IDE has no such functionality. The simple "template" folder with required structure is what most people use (based on my observations) -- then just copy-paste files manually. But you can also try some specialised tools -- maybe yeoman can do anything here? Simple batch/shell script may also do the job (at least for creating folder/files).

Comment: There is a function for IDEs, even for jetbrain's, but it doesn't support neither webstorm nor phpstorm https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Multifile.html

Comment: I am working with generator-gulp-angular, a Yeoman generator for AngularJS with GulpJS, but I haven't found a feature for this yet.

Comment: ReSharper and IDEA-based IDEs are 2 **different** things (at least from source point of view: first is done in C# and targets ReSharper only; second is done in Java). Saying "ReSharper has it" means nothing for PhpStorm/WebStorm